# Usage clarification: "and also"

Tags: word-usage, usage

I would like to know whether the usage of "also" followed by "and" is grammatically correct.

Even if it's grammatically correct I want to know if one of the words is redundant there.

Here is a sample sentence.

> I have attached the sample experience letter **and also** my relieving letter from the company.

Comment: It can be heard in informal speech, but I would probably steer clear in a professional note. You can delete "also". However, when people want a stronger word than "and" to draw attention to the change of list item, they often dispense with "and" and write "as well as", preceded by a comma. (But that reads - to me, at least - like an unnecessarily long way of saying "and".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be heard in informal speech, but I would probably steer clear in a professional note. You can delete "also". However, when people want a stronger word than "and" to draw attention to the change of list item, they often dispense with "and" and write "as well as", preceded by a comma. (But that reads - to me, at least - like an unnecessarily long way of saying "and".) – Luke Sawczak

Using just "and" suggest two items of roughly equal importance. Using "and also" suggests that the second item is supplementary to the first.